# Codeigniter using multiple arrays in a function?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
function SendAbsentSMS($date) {
    $student = $this->CI->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);
    $stu_setting = $this->CI->setting_model->getSkoolInfo();
    $MSG = "Dear Parent your ward " . $student['firstname'] . " " . $student['lastname'] . " " . $student['class'] . " " . $student['section'] . " is absent from his class on " . $student['date'] . ". Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
    $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
            '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
            '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
            '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
            '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['guardian_phone']) . 
            '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
   $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 

}
```

This is my function which sends SMS to each individual user, when there is single row output i am able to send an SMS (below is the generated array)

```
Array ( [id] => 25 [firstname] => Abhishek [lastname] => Mishra [email] => abhishekmishrashs@gmail.com [guardian_phone] => 8987190938 [roll_no] => 1 [class] => Class 1 [section] => Section A [date] => 2017-04-19 )
```

I am looking for a way to use multiple arrays output like below in the above function:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 25 [firstname] => Abhishek [lastname] => Mishra [email] => abhishekmishrashs@gmail.com [guardian_phone] => 8987190938 [roll_no] => 1 [class] => Class 1 [section] => Section A [date] => 2017-04-19 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [firstname] => ABHISHEK [lastname] => MISHRA [email] => abhishekmishrashs@gmail.com [guardian_phone] => 8987190938 [roll_no] => 1 [class] => Class 1 [section] => Section A [date] => 2017-04-19 ) )
```

and no matter how many arrays are there the function should send SMS individually to each users, i am unable to figure it out i can do it if there is single row but have no idea about multiple arrays.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach()`. What have you tried till so far?

Comment: Apologies sir, i am a newbie was trying foreach statement by looking at CI Documentation but can't figure it, this works fine if i use it as single row result  but i am looking for a solution which can make it work if i have multiple arrays at once, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$student = $this->CI->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);` returns only 1 row.

Update your model to return multiple rows as an array.

Then use this code.

```
function SendAbsentSMS($date) {
    $students = $this->CI->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);
    $stu_setting = $this->CI->setting_model->getSkoolInfo();
   foreach($students as $student)
   {
    $MSG = "Dear Parent your ward " . $student['firstname'] . " " . $student['lastname'] . " " . $student['class'] . " " . $student['section'] . " is absent from his class on " . $student['date'] . ". Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
    $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
            '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
            '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
            '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
            '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['guardian_phone']) . 
            '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
   $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how you are using `$student['firstname']`. In case of multi-dimensional array you should use this way `$student[0]['firstname']` or any other alternative way.

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Bikram Pahi, it worked, very very thanks sir :)

Comment: certainly want to do now but i can't, i am  newbie over stackoverflow and my reputation is less than 15 currently, but would do just after my repo score reaches to 15. Thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.

```
$student = $this->CI->stuattendence_model->student_daily_attendance($date);
$stu_setting = $this->CI->setting_model->getSkoolInfo();

    foreach($student as $val){
        $date = date();
        SendAbsentSMS($date,$val);
    }


    function SendAbsentSMS($date,$student) {
         $MSG = "Dear Parent your ward " . $student['firstname'] . " " . $student['lastname'] . " " . $student['class'] . " " . $student['section'] . " is absent from his class on " . $student['date'] . ". Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
        $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
        '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
        '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
        '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
        '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['guardian_phone']) . 
        '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
       $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 

    }
```

Comment: Can you try with this?

Comment: no sir, it's not working or it seems that i am doing the wrong way